# Push notification using ACS not working

Tags: javascript, mobile, titanium, appcelerator, push-notification

Hi i am implementing push notification using ACS.When i click on the register for push   notification  button it gives the following error.Failed to register for push! com.appcelerator.cloud.push.PushServiceException: Invalid  token request. Message:Proper Android Config can not be found, please provide a valid token

```
Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('#000');

  var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
  backgroundColor:'#ccc',
title:'Android Cloud Push Notification'
   })


   var CloudPush = require('ti.cloudpush');
CloudPush.debug = true;
CloudPush.enabled = true;
CloudPush.showTrayNotificationsWhenFocused = true;
CloudPush.focusAppOnPush = false;

 var deviceToken;

 var Cloud = require('ti.cloud');
  Cloud.debug = true;


  var submit = Ti.UI.createButton({
 title : 'Register For Push Notification',
  color:'#000',
  height : 53,
  width : 200,
     top : 100,
  });

    win.add(submit);

    submit.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
CloudPush.retrieveDeviceToken({
        success: function deviceTokenSuccess(e) {
            alert('Device Token: ' + e.deviceToken);
            deviceToken = e.deviceToken
            loginDefault();
        },
        error: function deviceTokenError(e) {
            alert('Failed to register for push! ' + e.error);
           }
  });
});


     function loginDefault(e){
 //Create a Default User in Cloud Console, and login
 Cloud.Users.login({
login: 'push123',
password: 'push123'
}, function (e) {
if (e.success) {
    alert("login success");
    defaultSubscribe();
  } else {
    alert('Error: ' +((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
    }
});
  }

   function defaultSubscribe(){
        Cloud.PushNotifications.subscribe({
            channel: 'alert',
            device_token: deviceToken,
            type: 'android'
        }, function (e){
            if (e.success) {
               alert('Subscribed for Push Notification!');
            }else{
                alert('Error:' +((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
            }
        });
 }

 CloudPush.addEventListener('callback', function (evt) {
 //alert(evt);
 //alert(evt.payload);
     );

   CloudPush.addEventListener('trayClickLaunchedApp', function (evt) {
  Ti.API.info('Tray Click Launched App (app was not running)');
 //alert('Tray Click Launched App (app was not running');
 });

  CloudPush.addEventListener('trayClickFocusedApp', function (evt) {
  Ti.API.info('Tray Click Focused App (app was already running)');
 //alert('Tray Click Focused App (app was already running)');
   });

win.open();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following link

http://www.titaniumtutorial.com/2012/06/appcelerator-cloud-push-notification-in.html?m=1

If it didn't solved your problem and you're using wifi, change it from wifi and try it in 3G or GPRS, there had some problem to register for push in wifi

Comment: Hi I have found the solution through your tutorial.I have not given the package name in ACS cloud